# Powershell installing msi

Tags: powershell, docker, iis, webdeploy

I am using docker with powershell. I want to download and install webdeploy .msi

I am using the following code:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01DC28EA-638C-4A22-A57B-4CEF97755C6C/WebDeploy_x86_en-US.msi  -OutFile webdeploy.msi; \
Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList /q, /i, -PassThru, webdeploy.msi ; \
Remove-Item -Force webdeploy.msi
```

When I run:
docker build -t test.

Everything goes fine.

When I then check the folder "Program Files (x86)" inside the container I dont see any folder "IIS".

I also tried:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/D/01DC28EA-638C-4A22-A57B-4CEF97755C6C/WebDeploy_x86_en-US.msi -OutFile webdeploy.msi; \
Start-Process msiexec -Wait -ArgumentList /q, /i, webdeploy.msi ; \
Remove-Item -Force webdeploy.msi
```

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, what is the purpose of the backslashes at the end of the lines? Second, I don't think -Passthru is a valid MSI parameter.

Comment: I tried with and without. Doesnt make any difference.

Comment: With and without the backslashes, or the -Passthru, or both?

Comment: both

Also I used backslashes for installing nodeJS .msi and that works fine.

Comment: first, unless docker requires the backslashes for some reason, remove them. Second try this: `-ArgumentList '/i webdeploy.msi /q'`

Comment: Tried it but I still dont see anything installed in the container.

Comment: Add logging to the install.

Comment: How do I add logging to the install?

Comment: At any command prompt type `msiexec /?`

Comment: So I write Start-Process msiexec /? -Wait -ArgumentList '/i webdeploy.msi /q' ; \

?

Comment: No you do what I said. You open a command prompt and type `msiexec /?` Then you read the help message to learn how to add logging to the install.

Comment: What's the base image? WOW64 is now an optional component, which if not enabled should break things further.

Comment: The logging helped. It seemed that it failed because of x86 version. When I changed it to x64 installation worked fine.